# How can I use PSP headphones with my Android phone?

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack

[image]

My Phone is Oukitel k-4000 Pro. I bought a headphone. But, then the problem came out. My phone does not support headphone output, just like in the picture. My phone's headphone jack is like everyone else, just a flat ledge.In my headset, There is an additional usb input.That's why I can not put my headphone on the phone. Would I break the usb output? Or is there another way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra part you've noticed is not USB at all: it's actually some extra contacts for the microphone and media/volume controls on these headphones. This a proprietary connector that's just for the PlayStation Portable (PSP), which these earphones were designed for.

If you break or cut off this part, you can use them like normal headphones, with a phone or anything else, but the mic and media controls won't work any more. They're not very good earphones, so you'd be better just using them with a PSP like they were intended, and getting some proper earphones to work with your phone.

Comment: Thank you very much for informing me. You gave me very good information. Can you explain me, Actually This headset for the Playstation not for the phone, isn't it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. You can tell because it has the PSP logo on them.